# In place string manipulation for character count

Tags: string, algorithm, in-place

Given a string, do in place replacement of every character with it's immediate count. 
eg:   "aaabbbcc" - "a3b3c2"
      "abab"     -  "a1b1a1b1"

Comment: If "aaabbbaaabbb" is given, should the output be "a3b3a3b3"?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu thats right

Comment: @vivek_23  I didn't get a good solution other than shifting every character one by one which is expensive

Comment: And are these strings using ```ASCII``` format?

Comment: @BharathPalaksha Ok, but you need to still post the code you tried. Also, in certaing languages, strings are immutable, like java. So, you can't do an in-place edit. But yes, you could create a new string and assign it to this old string variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```js
function getResult(input) {
  if(!input) {
   return '';                      // if string is empty, return ''
  }
  if (input.length === 1) {        // if string length is 1, return input + '1'
   return input + '1'
  }

  var inputLength = input.length; // total length of the input string
  var preChar = input[0];         // track previous character
  var count = 1;                  // count of the previous character

  for (var i = 1; i < inputLength; i++) {

    if (preChar === input[i]) {  // previous char and current char match
      preChar = input[i];        // update prevChar with current char
      count++;                   // count of prevChar is incremented
      if (i + 1 < inputLength) { // not the end of the string 
        input = input.substr(0, i) + '#' + input.substr(i + 1); // update with dummy char '#' to maintain the length of the string, later will be removed
      } else {                   // if it is the end of the string, update with count
        input = input.substr(0, i) + count + input.substr(i + 1);
      }
      continue;
    }

    // if current char is not matched with prevChar
    preChar = input[i];             // update the preChar with current char
     
    // update the input with prevChar count and current char
    input = input.substr(0, i) + count + input[i] + input.substr(i + 1); 
    inputLength++;                 // new count is added in the string, so total length of the string is increased by one
    i++;                           // increment the i also because total length is increased
    count = 1;                     // update the count with 1
    if (i + 1 === inputLength) {       // if it is last element     
      input = input.substr(0, i+1) + count + input.substr(i + 2); 
    }
  }
  input = input.replace(/\#/g, '') // remove dummy char '#' with ''
  return input;                    // return the input
}

console.log("result for aaabbbcc is ", getResult('aaabbbcc'))
console.log("result for abab is ", getResult('abab'))
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated for what OP wants

Comment: @ninesalt, i can understand your point of view and I also feel little so, but challenging part was to do it 'in-place' replacement. I am sure, there will be some more clean way to do it. But right now, I came up with above logic only, and i have to make sure that every edge case is handled.  But anyways, thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Comment: @Ankush Sharma ```input = input.substr(0, i) + '#' + input.substr(i + 1)``` this does not look like inline editing.

Comment: And this also seems to be a bug, you update the ```input[i  + 1]``` to be "```#```". If ```input[i + 1]``` is the same as ```preChar```, then you won't be able to detect that.

Comment: This isn't in place as substring internally creates a new string object. Consider an array of characters and try to manipulate there.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer assumes the OP uses `ASCII`

### Analysis of the requirement of the the OP

#### Analysis of the bytes required:

1. When there is 1 repeat only, 2 bytes are needed.
2. When there are 2 repeats, 2 bytes are needed.
3. When there are 3, 2 bytes are needed.
4. When there are 9, 2 bytes.
5. When there are 99, 3 bytes.
6. When there are 999, 4 bytes.
7. When there are (2^64 - 1) repeats, only 20 bytes are needed.

As you can see, the bytes required to express the integer are `log10(N)`(at least 1) where `N` is the number of repeats.

#### Repeat-once

So, when there is only 1 repeat and there is no spare space, it has to keep iterating until

1. sequence that have more bytes than needed(have at least 3 repeats) to give it space
2. to `reallocate` when the end is reached
   (In a string where most repeat at least twice or thrice and those who only repeat once are not gathered in one place, this is seldom required. This algorithm makes this assumption).

Then, the string will be modified backward to prevent any overwritten of data. This work because for each repeat-once  sequence, it will take up double bytes to store them, so when the sequence at `i` will be written at `2i`.

## `C++14` Code

````cpp
#include <algorithm>

#include <cassert>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// Definition of helper functions for converting ints to string(raw and no need for format string).

template <class size_t, class UnsignedInt,
          class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<UnsignedInt>::value>>
size_t to_str_len(UnsignedInt i) noexcept
{
    size_t cnt = 0;

    do {
        ++cnt;
        i /= 10;
    } while (i > 0);

    return cnt;
}

/*
 * out should either points to the beginning of array   or the last.
 * step should be either 1 or -1.
 */
template <class RandomAccessIt, class UnsignedInt,
          class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<UnsignedInt>::value>>
auto uitos_impl(RandomAccessIt out, int step, UnsignedInt i) noexcept
{
    do {
        *out = static_cast<char>(i % 10) + 48;
        out += step;
        i /= 10;
    } while (i > 0);

    return out;
}

template <class BidirectionalIt>
void reverse_str(BidirectionalIt beg, BidirectionalIt end) noexcept
{
    do {
        std::iter_swap(beg++, --end);
    } while (beg < end);
}

template <class RandomAccessIt, class UnsignedInt>
auto uitos(RandomAccessIt beg, UnsignedInt i) noexcept
{
    auto ret = uitos_impl(beg, 1, i);

    // Reverse the string to get the right order
    reverse_str(beg, ret);

    return ret;
}

template <class RanIt, class UnsignedInt>
auto r_uitos(RanIt last, UnsignedInt i) noexcept
{
    return uitos_impl(last, -1, i);
}

template <class size_t, class RandomAccessIt>
size_t count_repeat(RandomAccessIt beg, RandomAccessIt end) noexcept
{
    auto first = beg;
    auto &val = *beg;
    do {
        ++beg;
    } while (beg != end && *beg == val);

    return beg - first;
}

template <class size_t, class RandomAccessIt>
size_t r_count_repeat(RandomAccessIt last) noexcept
{
    auto it = last;
    auto &val = *it;
    do {
        --it;
    } while (*it == val);

    return last - it;
}

template <class string,
          class size_type = typename string::size_type>
struct character_count
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<size_type>::value,
                     "size_type should be unsigned");
    static_assert(!std::is_empty<size_type>::value,
                     "size_type should not be empty");

private:
    using str_size_t = typename string::size_type;
    using str_it = typename string::iterator;

    static_assert(std::is_same<typename string::value_type, char>::value,
                     "Only support ASCII");
    static_assert(sizeof(size_type) <= sizeof(str_size_t),
                     "size_type should not be bigger than typename string::size_type");


    string str;

    str_it in;
    str_it out;
    str_it end;
    size_type len;

    void cnt_repeat() noexcept
    {
        assert(in != end);
        len = count_repeat<size_type>(in, str.end());
    }

    void advance_in() noexcept
    {
        assert(in != end);
        in += len;
        assert(in <= end);
    }

    void process_impl()
    {
        assert(in != end);
        assert(out <= in);

        // The main loop
        do {
            cnt_repeat();
            if (len > 1 || out < in) {
                *out = *in;
                out = uitos(out + 1, len);

                advance_in();

                assert(out <= in);
            } else {
                auto first = find_enough_space();
                auto deduced_first = write_backward();

                assert(first == deduced_first);
            }
        } while (in != end);
    }

    auto find_enough_space()
    {
        assert(out == in);

        auto first = in;
        size_type bytes_required = 0;

        do {
            cnt_repeat();

            advance_in();
            bytes_required += to_str_len<size_type>(len) + 1;

            if (size_type(in - first) >= bytes_required) {
                out = first + bytes_required;
                return first;
            }
        } while (in != str.end());

        auto first_offset = first - str.begin();
        // Hopefully this path won't be executed.
        auto new_size = first_offset + bytes_required;

        auto original_size = str.size();
        assert(new_size > original_size);

        str.resize(new_size);

        first = str.begin() + first_offset;
        out = str.end();
        in = str.begin() + original_size;
        end = str.begin() + original_size;

        return first;
    }

    auto write_backward() noexcept
    {
        auto original_out = out--;
        auto original_in = in--;

        do {
            len = r_count_repeat<size_type>(in);

            out = r_uitos(out, len);
            *out-- = *((in -= len) + 1);
        } while (out != in);

       auto ret = out + 1;

       out = original_out;
       in = original_in;

       return ret;
    }

public:
    character_count(string &&arg):
        str(std::move(arg)), in(str.begin()), out(str.begin()), end(str.end())
    {}

    character_count(const string &arg):
        str(arg), in(str.begin()), out(str.begin()), end(str.end())
    {}

    /*
     * ```str``` should not be empty and should not have non-visible character
     */
    auto& process()
    {
        assert(!str.empty());
        process_impl();

        str.erase(out, str.end());

        return *this;
    }

    auto& get_result() & noexcept
    {
        return str;
    }
    auto&& get_result() && noexcept
    {
        return std::move(str);
    }
    auto& get_result() const& noexcept
    {
        return str;
    }

    /*
     * ```str``` should not be empty and should not have non-visible character
     */
    auto& set_string(const string &arg) noexcept
    {
        str = arg;

        in = str.begin();
        out = str.begin();
        end = str.end();

        return *this;
    }
    /*
     * ```str``` should not be empty and should not have non-visible character
     */
    auto& set_string(string &&arg) noexcept
    {
        str = std::move(arg);

        in = str.begin();
        out = str.begin();
        end = str.end();

        return *this;
    }
};
````

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable, so there’s no way of doing it in place. Instead, I will do it like below using a stack:

```
class Solution:
    def count_char(self, s):
        stack=[]
        counter=0
        res=""
     
        for char in s:
            if not stack : #if stack is empty add character and increment the count
                stack.append(char)
                counter=counter+1
            elif stack[-1]==char: # if last character same as current ,increment counter
                counter=counter+1
            else:
                stack.append(str(counter)) # else means we are having a new character ,so append the count of previous group and current character,also set counter=1 for new group
                stack.append(char)
                counter=1
        return "".join(stack)+str(counter) # add the last groups count

s=Solution()

st1="aaabbbccc"
st2="abac"

print(s.count_char(st1))

print(s.count_char(st2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Javascript, this is how I would do it. Just match all the groups with a regex and loop over them:

```js
function charCount (str) {
  const exp = /(\w)\1*/g
  let matches = (str).match(exp)
  let output = ''

  matches.forEach(group => {
    output += group[0] + group.length
  })

  return output
}

const str = 'abab'
const str2 = 'aaabbbcc'

console.log(charCount(str))   // a1b1a1b1
console.log(charCount(str2))  // a3b3c2
```

Comment: This is not in place, you are appending output to a new variable. Question is not specific to language, it is an algorithmic question.